# Are custom _id fields in MongoDB still of type ObjectId

Tags: mongodb

I'm building a project with MongoDB, but I'm a little bit confused on how the `_id` field works. My understanding is that, by default, MongoDB will generate an object of type `ObjectId` and assign it as the id.

However, in my server, I'm assigning an arbitrary string as the `_id` of an object. What I haven't quite understood yet: Is this string somehow converted to an `ObjectId`, or does the type of the `_id` field *change* to `string`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB will generate an `_id` field with an `ObjectId` value if an `_id` field does not exist in the document. If you create the `_id` by your own, then you can use whatever datatype you like to use. MongoDB does not modify it.

The only constraint is, it must be a unique value.